# Checked CheckBoxes

Tags: php, html

I need to store the ID of  only the checked check boxes from the table of  displaying products to use them in other things this is my code

```
while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)){
            $pID= $row2[0];
            $pName = $row2[1];
            $pDes = $row2[2];
            $pSale = $row2[5];
            $pPrice = $row2[4];
            $pPhoto = $row2[6];
            if($counter % 4 == 0)echo "<tr> ";
            echo " 
            <td> Name: '".$pName."' <br>  ID: '".$pID."' <br>      Price: '".$pPrice."' <br> <div id='parent'>
            <img src='".$pPhoto."' width = '180' height = '180'/> 
            <br><input type='checkbox' name='item[]' value='".$pID."'" ." >
            <div id='popup' >Description: ".$pDes." <br> Sale  Percent: ".$pSale." 

            </div></div></td> ";
```

any help to mange how to store only the id of checked ckeckboxes (item[]) in array

Comment: you didnt flag js, are you doing this after a post?

Comment: If you are using form and want to get array of stored id when checkbox is checked after submitting the form. them no need to change the code it will select only checked checkbox values in array.

Comment: It depend if you want to do it in server (php) or if you want to do it in client  and after send only checked (javascript)

Comment: Welcome to SO, Sorry to say, but it's an easy answer to a terrible bad formatted question, please rephrase your question, add *relevant code* & tags, explain what you tried so far and where it fails. ***[Recommended reading](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)***.

Answer (score -2):

If you are using form and want to get array of stored id when checkbox is checked after submitting the form. them no need to change the code it will select only checked checkbox values in array.

Without form we have to use jquery that answered by "Khaled Ouertani".